# Why doesn't all characters fit into new TEXT field in new table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, fieldtype

I aggregate several texts from varchar(140) with GROUP_CONCAT fields in MySQL into a new table. Automatically the new field becomes of field type TEXT which according to the documentation should hold 65535 characters. Still it's only some of the texts characters that shows up in the new table (column "full_text" below). I've checked and there is more texts, and thus characters, that should be in the new tables column. I haven't changed anything in the MySQL server such as max_package_size, it's all default.

Here is my MySQL query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempsumdate;
CREATE TABLE tempsumdate ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci AS
SELECT tw.from_user, MONTH(tw.created_at) AS month, GROUP_CONCAT(tw.text) AS full_text  
FROM tweets AS tw
GROUP BY tw.from_user, month;´
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTLM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

by default group_concat() has a length limit of 1024 chars.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Is there a way round that so I can fit in more characters and achieve the same thing?

Comment: read the linked docs. it tells you what system settings to change.